# When VPN is connected, no one can ping me?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I have a strange problem, every thing is working fine when am not connected to VPN, and people in my local network can ping me, am using FortiClient to connect to my work VPN, and when I'm connected, no one can ping me using either local network ip or VPN network ip,

I'm using win XP, and switched the firewall off, but also no luck,

any help is appreciated,

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably better suited to SuperUser but the basic answer is thus:

The default behaviour of most VPN software is to tunnel all network traffic through the tunnel to the other end.  To all intents and purposes your machine ceases to exist on the local network and can only communicate with the remote network that you're VPN'd into.

There is an approach called "Split Tunnel" which many VPN clients support which allows local traffic to stay local, while tunneling everything else.  Have a look in the documentation for FortiClient to see if it offers this mode of operation.

Answer (score 0):

If all the trafic go through vpn, when somebody try to ping you, his ping also go throught vpn tunnel. And in this case, you use the firewall of your company, which may block ping to you.